# How to calculate and common capacity factors for gas power plants

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-engineering

I am wondering the following, and didn't find anything online or here in the forum:

1) How is the capacity or load factor of a gas power plant calculated: (GROSS electricity generated)/(maximum capacity x time period) or (NET electricity generated)/(maximum capacity x time period)?

2) What range is common for a gas power plant capacity factor (gas turbine, steam turbine, CCGT) when the plant is operated at a profit?